# Selenium urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nenuk\OneDrive\Desktop\Creator\32.py", line 556, in <module>
    driver = uc.Chrome(options=opts)
  File "C:\Users\nenuk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\__init__.py", line 258, in __init__
    self.patcher.auto()
  File "C:\Users\nenuk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\patcher.py", line 178, in auto
    self.unzip_package(self.fetch_package())
  File "C:\Users\nenuk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\patcher.py", line 287, in fetch_package
    return urlretrieve(download_url)[0]
  File "C:\Users\nenuk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 240, in urlretrieve
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
  File "C:\Users\nenuk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 215, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\nenuk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 521, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\nenuk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 630, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "C:\Users\nenuk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 559, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\nenuk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 492, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\nenuk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 639, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

How i can solve this problem, last time i re-downloaded everything it worked but right now it doesnt.

Comment: For reference, this issue in `undetected-chromedriver` was caused by a change to the `chromedriver` download location: https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/chrome-for-testing/pull/108

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
    def fetch_package(self):
    """
    Downloads ChromeDriver from source

    :return: path to downloaded file
    """
    zip_name = f"chromedriver_{self.platform_name}.zip"
    if self.is_old_chromedriver:
        download_url = "%s/%s/%s" % (self.url_repo, self.version_full.vstring, zip_name)
    else:
        zip_name = zip_name.replace("_", "-", 1)
        #download_url = "https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/%s/%s/%s"
        download_url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-for-testing-public/%s/%s/%s"
        download_url %= (self.version_full.vstring, self.platform_name, zip_name)

    logger.debug("downloading from %s" % download_url)
    return urlretrieve(download_url)[0]
```

You need to change fetch_package(self) in undetected_chromedriver\patcher.py

Since the old download_url can not work to get the chrome driver, you should use 'https://storage.googleapis.com/' to replace the 'https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/'.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved in v3.5.5 for undetected_chromedriver.

uninstall and install undetected_chromedriver again.

Comment: Using 3.5.5 here and still getting `undetected_chromedriver.patcher:downloading from https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/123.0.6312.58/mac-x64/chromedriver-mac-x64.zip`and `HTTP Error 404: Not Found`

Comment: Please update undetected_chromedriver. v3.5.5 was uptodate when i wrote this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to version incompatibility. You need to upgrade your undetected_chromedriver.

Copy and paste this in the terminal

```
pip install --upgrade undetected_chromedriver
```

Optionally, you might need to upgrade your Chrome browser as well

download the installer [here](https://www.google.com/chrome/)

Otherwise you might get

```
An error occurred in the main function: Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at xxx.x.x.x:xxxxx
from session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version zzz
Current browser version is yyy.y.yyyy.yyy
```

This should solve the issue.